# How to set KeySize on RSA?

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, rsa

How do you set the key size on the `RSA` class?

There is no key size option with `RSA.Create()` and setting `KeySize` on `RSA` after it has been created does not have any effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### If you are using .NET Framework:

There's no provider-unaware solution. You have to use the `RSACryptoServiceProvider(int)` constructor or intentionally create an `RSACng` object.

### If you are using .NET Core:

```
RSA rsa = RSA.Create();
rsa.KeySize = someValue
```

is the right approach, it works on all possible answers for RSA.Create().

### If you are using Mono:

I don't know which behavior it matches.

### If you are from the future:

https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/8688 is tracking the future addition of `RSA.Create(int)` (and `RSA.Create(RSAParameters)`) to help solve this problem.

### A scoped method which requires cross-compiling:

(Defining NETFX correctly for your build and lining that up in a nuget package is an exercise left to the reader)

```
internal static RSA RsaCreate(int keySize)
{
#if NETFX
    // If your baseline is .NET 4.6.2 or higher prefer RSACng
    // or 4.6+ if you are never giving the object back to the framework
    // (4.6.2 improved the framework's handling of those objects)
    // On older versions RSACryptoServiceProvider is the only way to go.
    return new RSACng(keySize);
#else
    RSA rsa = RSA.Create();
    rsa.KeySize = keySize;

    if (rsa.KeySize != keySize)
        throw new Exception("Setting rsa.KeySize had no effect");

    return rsa;
#endif
}
```

And, of course, if you're from the future you could call the new Create overload directly in a higher precedence #if.

Answer (score 2):

RSA is just an abstract class for RSA implementations.  You should use `RSACryptoServiceProvider`.

```
RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(bitSize);
```

Note that the key doesn't get generated until you attempt to use it, so don't put the constructor by itself in a background worker etc.

Comment: We'll leave the discussion about instantiating an "abstract" class and the "lazy" generation of RSA keys for another forum, but yeah, there it is...

Comment: The problem is RSACryptoServiceProvider is not available on non-Windows platforms.

Comment: @JamesNewton-King There arent any other RSA implementations in .NET.  Im pretty sure it still works on mono though.

Comment: Sure there are. If you're on .NET Core on Linux then `RSA.Create()` will create an implementation of `RSA` that runs on Linux.

Comment: `RSACryptoServiceProvider` doesn't run on Linux on .NET Core. If you even reference the NuGet package that contains it your application will fail that the package isn't supported on that platform. Instead what you do is just reference the base algorithm package and `RSA.Create()` returns an different implementation depending on your environment. I don't have Linux to test but I know that `RSA.Create()` on UWP will return `RSACng` - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsacng(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @LukePark With the exception of creating a new key on .NET Framework, any time you write "RSACryptoServiceProvider" specifically in your code is a bug. X509Certificate2.GetRSAPublicKey(), for example, will never return an RSACryptoServiceProvider instance (unless it does on Mono).

Comment: This does not work either. I am on .NET Standard 2.1